# Get vue component from event

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am building a drag and drop feature in my application where the drop area looks like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="layers-panel" @dragover="onDragOver" @drop="onDragDrop">
    <layer
      v-for="(layer, index) in layers"
      :key="layer.name"
      :info="layer"
      :offset="index"
      ref="layer"
    ></layer>
  </div>
</template>
```

Then the draggable items look like this:

```html
<template>
  <div class="layer" draggable="true" @dragstart="onDragStart">
    <!-- Content of draggable element -->
  </div>
</template>
```

In my drag over event, I want to get the current component that the element relates to, so when I drag an item over the `<div class="layer"...>` element I would like to get that component. I am not sure how to get access to this since an event is passed to the `@dragover="onDragOver"` event which only gives me access to html elements and not Vue components.

This is what my current `dragover` event looks like:

```js
    public onDragOver(evt: DragEvent) {
      evt.preventDefault()
      if (!evt.target) return
      let layer = (evt.target as HTMLElement).closest('.layer') as HTMLElement
    }
```

How can I get the component that that element belongs to?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what you plan to do with the component? Is it about the component or is it actually about adding the `layer` to `layers`?

Comment: If you think of **Gimp** or **PhotoShop** they have layers, and you can drag the layers around to reorder them. Each of my layers is a layer component that you can drag to reorder. The issue that I am having is finding where the user dropped the layer in the list of elements. So I was thinking of just getting the offset of the component and moving the layer there...

Comment: You could just use the `@dragend` event in the `layer` and emit to the parent in that event.  You could even emit the instance e.g. `this.$emit('layerDragEnd', this);`.

Answer (score 2):

Vue certainly allows you to [access a component instance](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-edge-cases.html#Element-amp-Component-Access) however I don't think it's necessary to reaching your actual goal: reordering of components via drag-and-drop.

Drag-and-drop means we're limited by what's afforded by [DragEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DragEvent):

- We can access the [target element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) e.g. the element being dragged or dropped on
- We can set arbitrary data via [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer)

You can't determine where the element is dropped because your drop element contains all the layers. Instead if each layer is a drop element, then you can determine which one it is via [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/dragover_event) via `event.target`.

We also need to identify which element corresponding to the `layers` array we're dragging/dropping on. This can be achieved by binding the index of each `layer` as an attribute so we can access it via `event.target`.

To keep it simple, I'll use the `id` attribute so I can just access it later via `event.target.id`:

```
<div
  v-for="(layer, idx) in layers"
  :key="idx"
  :id="idx"
  draggable="true"
  @dragstart="dragstart"
>
  <div
    :id="idx"
    class="draggable"
    @dragover="dragover"
    @drop="drop"
  >
    {{ layer }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Note I bind the same index to id so I can correctly identify the target layer.

We'll also need to ensure we can identify the element that was dragged since on `drop` we'll only have the drop element via `event.target`. We can do this by setting data in `DataTransfer` when we first start the drag:

```
dragstart(event) {
  event.dataTransfer.setData("selectedIdx", event.target.id);
},
```

Now on drop we have access to both and can manipulate `layers` as we desire:

```
drop(event) {
  var selectedIdx = event.dataTransfer.getData("selectedIdx");
  var targetIdx = event.target.id;
  var selected = this.layers.splice(selectedIdx, 1)[0];
  this.layers.splice(targetIdx, 0, selected);
},
```

[Example codepen](https://codepen.io/xieliming/pen/PooLJrj)